# Java Robot: Ways to Stop During Cycle

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent, awtrobot

I'm creating a simple bot for this flash game on my pc. The bot behaves perfectly, but **I am looking for a way to stop or pause the bot mid-way through its cycle.**

To clarify, I am looking for a way to implement something like *keybindings* except I want to use my browser as the focus instead of a *JFrame*.

With this, I could press a key and the robot would immediately stop.

Here's my current code for context:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Digging {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException {

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(5000); // buffer time to click over to browser
        action(robot);

    }

    public static void action(Robot robot) {

        robot.mouseMove(1140, 415);

        for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                // dig
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.delay(200);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.delay(300);
                // move
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
                robot.delay(100);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
            } // dig right
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                // dig
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.delay(200);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.delay(300);
                // move
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                robot.delay(100);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
            } // dig left
        } // dig
    } // action
} // driver
```

Comment: How about a MouseListener? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: Sure, how'd I do that? Remember, I'm not using JFrame for a focus, i'm just clicking over to google chrome once my program starts.

Comment: Okay, my previous comment was somewhat misguided, but this might still help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473808/mouselistener-without-a-gui

Comment: I tried that and it worked! But it’s still not nearly as elegant as pressing a key. If anybody could find a way to scan if a key is held down without a jframe that’d be amazing